# WordPress post pagination not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to load my WordPress posts using ajax. I implemented the following functions to do the pagination for me.

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
          'posts_per_page' => 6, 
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'paged' => $paged
        ) 
      );
<?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $the_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous &larr; ' ); wp_reset_query();?>
```

When I try to navigate through the paginated link (Next/Previous), the URL is looking like this:

```
http://localhost/vendor/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?paged=2
```

The URL i am trying to get:

```
http://localhost/vendor/vendorpage/page/2/
```

Is there any way to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code -

```
ob_start(); // Turn output buffering on
        global $paged;
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                $the_query->the_post();
               //your code
            }

            $big = 999999999;
            echo paginate_links(
                array(
                    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max(
                        1,
                        get_query_var('paged')
                    ),
                    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages //$q is your custom query
                )
            );
        }
        return ob_get_clean();
        wp_reset_query();
```