# Is it possible to redirect the user to the first page of pagination if the pagination is empty In wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to redirect the user to the first page of the pagination if the pagination is empty.
I have three bootstrap tabs (Both, Blog, News). The blog tab contains 5 posts. The news tab contains more than 12 posts. I am displaying 6 posts per page. The issue here is that if I am on the second page of News tab and click the Blog tab, the second page of the blog tab is opening (which does not exist).
For better Understanding Here is my code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#sectionA" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Section A</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#sectionB" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Section B</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#sectionC" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Section C</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade show active">
      <?php
      if(1 != $paged) {
        
}
      ?>
  <section class="vendor-section-2 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        
        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
                
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 
                array( 
                  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'paged' => $paged
                ) 
              );
              $page_amount = $the_query->max_num_pages; 
     
    
?>
        <div class="container pagination-count">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p>Page <span><?php echo $paged ?></span> of <span><?php echo $page_amount ?></span> </p>  
                </div>


            </div>

     
        </div>
<?php
    
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
?>                                                 

            <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.111" height="23.646" viewBox="0 0 24.111 23.646" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                                <path
                                    id="Path_84"
                                    data-name="Path 84"
                                    d="M9.544.241a3.061,3.061,0,0,1,3.348.642c1.4,1.427,4.322,1.638,5.638,2.976,1.49,1.518,1.358,4.151,2.856,5.584a7.9,7.9,0,0,1,2.163,8.913,7.942,7.942,0,0,1-3.789,4.323c-6.319,2.6-14.617-.268-18.3-5.889-1.8-2.745-2.12-6.848.122-9.133C3.947,5.245,5.608,1.887,9.544.241Z"
                                    fill="#f3943f"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Read More 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php
                        
                    endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();  
                
                endif;?>
            <div class="next-prev-btn">
                <!-- then the pagination links -->
                <?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $the_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous &larr; ' ); wp_reset_query();?>

            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

  </div>
  <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
  <section class="vendor-section-2 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        
        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
            
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 
                array( 
                  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'category_name' => 'blog',
                  'paged' => $paged
                ) 
              );
              $page_amount = $the_query->max_num_pages; 
     
    
?>
        <div class="container pagination-count">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p>Page <span><?php echo $paged ?></span> of <span><?php echo $page_amount ?></span> </p>  
                </div>


            </div>

     
        </div>
<?php
    
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
?>                                                 

            <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.111" height="23.646" viewBox="0 0 24.111 23.646" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                                <path
                                    id="Path_84"
                                    data-name="Path 84"
                                    d="M9.544.241a3.061,3.061,0,0,1,3.348.642c1.4,1.427,4.322,1.638,5.638,2.976,1.49,1.518,1.358,4.151,2.856,5.584a7.9,7.9,0,0,1,2.163,8.913,7.942,7.942,0,0,1-3.789,4.323c-6.319,2.6-14.617-.268-18.3-5.889-1.8-2.745-2.12-6.848.122-9.133C3.947,5.245,5.608,1.887,9.544.241Z"
                                    fill="#f3943f"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Read More 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php
                        
                    endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();  
                
                endif;?>
            <div class="next-prev-btn">
                <!-- then the pagination links -->
                <?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $the_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous &larr; ' ); wp_reset_query();?>

            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

  </div>
  <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade">
  <section class="vendor-section-2 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        
        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
            
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 
                array( 
                  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'category_name' => 'news',
                  'paged' => $paged
                ) 
              );
              $page_amount = $the_query->max_num_pages; 
     
    
?>
        <div class="container pagination-count">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p>Page <span><?php echo $paged ?></span> of <span><?php echo $page_amount ?></span> </p>  
                </div>


            </div>

     
        </div>
<?php
    
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
?>                                                 

            <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.111" height="23.646" viewBox="0 0 24.111 23.646" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                                <path
                                    id="Path_84"
                                    data-name="Path 84"
                                    d="M9.544.241a3.061,3.061,0,0,1,3.348.642c1.4,1.427,4.322,1.638,5.638,2.976,1.49,1.518,1.358,4.151,2.856,5.584a7.9,7.9,0,0,1,2.163,8.913,7.942,7.942,0,0,1-3.789,4.323c-6.319,2.6-14.617-.268-18.3-5.889-1.8-2.745-2.12-6.848.122-9.133C3.947,5.245,5.608,1.887,9.544.241Z"
                                    fill="#f3943f"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Read More 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php
                        
                    endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();  
                
                endif;?>
            <div class="next-prev-btn">
                <!-- then the pagination links -->
                <?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $the_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous &larr; ' ); wp_reset_query();?>

            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would not use this approach, since pagination essentially reloads the page and serves up the next batch of posts. You should look into doing an `ajax` request instead for each post type - that way you do not affect any other post type on the page.

Comment: @disinfor I tried something like that. But I also got some error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384815/wordpress-post-pagination-not-working-with-ajax/69389882#69389882

Comment: Pagination wont be empty at 1st place. If its written properly. WP wont give you random number of pages for pagination.

Comment: But, can I change https://example.com/vendor-page/page/2 to https://example.com/vendor-page on selecting new tab?